# MySql 8 is not using spatial index

Tags: mysql, indexing, spatial

I have spatial column named **SHAPE** with SRID 4269 and spatial index. When i make the query

```
select geoid10 as zipcode from tl_2019_us_zcta510
   where st_intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(30.330280 -82.759009)',4269),SHAPE);
```

it takes 2 minutes to run. The table contains 33k records.

I checked the query whether it is using index

```
explain select geoid10 as zipcode from tl_2019_us_zcta510
   where st_intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(30.330280 -82.759009)',4269),SHAPE);
```

and i get the result

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tl_2019_us_zcta510 | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 28206 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

This clearly shows that the query is not using spatial index.

I ran the same query in Mysql 5.7 and it is using spatial index.

Can anybody help me with this.
Is there any other configurational change i should look out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This does not answer the question, but may add some insight.)

The **8.0.4** Changelog says (I added bolding):

---

Incompatible Change: **Previously**, these spatial functions **ignored** the spatial reference system (SRS) for geometry arguments and computed results on a Cartesian plane. They now support computations for geometry arguments that specify a geographic SRS: ST_Distance_Sphere(), ST_IsSimple(), ST_IsValid(), ST_Length().

Previously, these spatial functions ignored the SRS for any geometry arguments and computed results on a Cartesian plane. They now produce an error when invoked with geometry arguments that specify a geographic SRS: ST_Area(), ST_Buffer(), ST_Centroid(), ST_ConvexHull(), ST_Difference(), ST_Envelope(), **ST_Intersection()**, ST_IsClosed(), ST_MakeEnvelope(), ST_Simplify(), ST_SymDifference(), ST_Union(), ST_Validate().

Previously, these spatial functions permitted geometry arguments with an undefined SRS. They now produce an error when invoked with geometry arguments that have an undefined SRS: ST_Dimension(), ST_Distance_Sphere(), ST_EndPoint(), ST_ExteriorRing(), ST_GeometryN(), ST_GeometryType(), ST_InteriorRingN(), ST_IsEmpty(), ST_IsSimple(), ST_IsValid(), ST_Length(), ST_NumGeometries(), ST_NumInteriorRing(), ST_NumInteriorRings(), ST_NumPoints(), ST_PointN(), ST_StartPoint(), ST_SwapXY(), ST_X(), ST_Y().

Previously, the ST_GeoHash() spatial function accepted points with any SRID. ST_GeoHash() now accepts only points with SRID 0 or 4326.
Note

If spatial data contains geometry values that now are **interpreted differently** by the functions just listed, existing queries using these functions will return different results, compared to previous MySQL versions.

---

**My comment:**  What is 4269? Perhaps only 4326 is handled? Will it run faster with 4326?

Comment: I have another doubt. doing this using innodb engine works fine. But as I am using mysql ndb cluster, i want to use NDB engine so that data gets replicated across nodes. As ndb doesnt support spatial reference system, what should be the alternate solution?

Comment: Replication is available with InnoDB.  Please explain further why you picked NDB.  (NDB serves a small niche; InnoDB serves a broad range of applications.)

Comment: i wanted HA for 3 host setup with no single point of failure. Also all hosts should perform both read and write

Comment: @ArbazSheikh - See Galera (included with MariaDB) which allows read and write on 3+ nodes. or Group Replication / Innodb Cluster (from Oracle).  Both have no SPOF and do automatic failover.  Both handle InnoDB and SPATIAL (MariaDB 10.2 / MySQL 5.7)

Answer (score 0):

I solved after I read this one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260757/mysql-8-not-using-spatial-index

Basically, you need to define a default SRID for your column at table creation (or with ALTER).

In your case, the column *geoid10* in table *tl_2019_us_zcta510* should be defined with SRID 4269, then it should correctly use the spatial index.
It worked for me.

This is the correct answer quoted from Nikita at dba.stackexchange.com:

> The SRID attribute makes a spatial column SRID-restricted, which has
> these implications:
>
> The column can contain only values with the given SRID. Attempts to
> insert values with a different SRID produce an error.
>
> The optimizer can use SPATIAL indexes on the column. See Section
> 8.3.3, “SPATIAL Index Optimization”.
>
> Spatial columns with no SRID attribute are not SRID-restricted and
> accept values with any SRID. However, the optimizer cannot use SPATIAL
> indexes on them until the column definition is modified to include an
> SRID attribute, which may require that the column contents first be
> modified so that all values have the same SRID.